# What is the best way to store hostname and port?

Tags: java, networking, uri

I need a map in which I store **ID** (key) and **hostname:port** (value). What type of object should I use to store the value?

I tried something like this:

```
map.put(id, new URI("localhost:2222"));
```

But after I'd executed

```
entry.getValue().getHost()
```

and

```
entry.getValue().getPort()
```

I got: null and -1.

I need only hostname and port, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an InetSocketAddress.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about InetSocketAddress.

Answer (score 0):

A map. The two lines you show are the same, so I'm not sure why you got different results, but without more code, it's impossible to determine why your lookup failed unless the URI didn't parse correctly.

Comment: I corrected my question. I do new URI("localhost:2222"); so I expect that getHost() will return "localhost" and getPort() will return 2222 but unfortunately I get null and -1.

Comment: @Radek Since you don't pass in a scheme, that's what'll happen--see [the docs for the `String` ctor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI(java.lang.String)).